# using leaflet lib to plot 34 points on map

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio

I have a dataset of 34 rows and 3 columns. The columns are country, latitude and longitude. I am trying to plot all the 34 points on that map.

Code:

```
library(RODBC)
library(googleVis)
con <- odbcConnect("Data", uid = "username", pwd = "password")
Geo <- sqlQuery(con, "select * from ANA.R.vwGeo")

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addCircles(lng=Geo$lon, lat=Geo$lat, popup=Geo$country)
m # Print the map
```

This code prints the circles on the map but only 8 of them. After checking i realized that it only plotted the top 8 rows and ignored the rest? Not sure how to change this.

```
structure(list(country = c("Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", 
"Belgium", "Brazil", "Canada", "China", "Denmark", "Europe", 
"France", "Germany", "India", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", 
"Korea, Republic of", "Norway", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal"
), lat = c(-36.536119, -24.211317, 47.751901, 50.755453, -11.066766, 
60.739101, 35.716703, 55.946866, NA, 46.97068, 51.295789, 22.518114, 
53.297545, 31.191818, 43.259406, 36.110262, 36.641155, 62.153742, 
15.137269, 52.22507, 39.77707), Ion = c(-64.653608, 134.654116, 
14.559724, 4.646748, -50.060384, -101.625, 103.696658, 9.554184, 
NA, 2.846033, 10.563983, 78.560473, -7.812353, 34.881909, 12.419802, 
138.462604, 128.085175, 9.363357, 121.232504, 19.452793, -7.908592
)), .Names = c("country", "lat", "Ion"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L)) -> Geo
```

[image]

Comment: Reproducible. Example. Please.

Comment: https://fsaiyed.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/capture.png

Comment: @FaizSaiyed that is an image, not a reproducible example. You can paste the output of `dput(Geo)` within your question, just indent it 4 spaces like you would a code block.

Comment: oh yes thats right. sorry about that. im fairly new to this still. thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your plot, the issue is likely caused by `NA` values for row 9 "Europe".
Not sure why plotting stops, but you can at least try with `NA` lines removed with:

```
Geo <- Geo[!is.na(Geo$lon) & !is.na(Geo$lat), ]
```

Comment: thanks to all. Max what you said about the Null value was the problem i think. Now that i got eid of it, it works fine. Thanks to everyone else too.